# How to create inline policy with AWS API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am writing code which requires IAM role to be created programmatically in Java. I would like an inline policy attached to the role instead of a managed policy. I can only find [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-iam-policies.html#list-attached-role-policies) and [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRole.html) to create a role and a managed policy separately, then attach the managed policy to the existing IAM role.

How can I create an IAM role with inline policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java there is [putRolePolicy](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iam/IamClient.html#putRolePolicy-java.util.function.Consumer-) for that:

> **Adds** or updates an **inline policy** document that is embedded in the specified IAM role.